# intersection of ragged list

Tags: python, intersection

I want to write a function that takes a ragged list from user input and find the intersection

```py
def intersection():
    intersect_list = []
    for i in lst[0]:
        for j in lst[1]:
            if i == j:
                intersect_list.append(i)
    return intersect_list


lst = ("enter list:")
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "ragged list"? Because what I hear is "list of lists where the sublists have different lengths", and I don't see an immediate way to define a mathematical "intersection" on such structures. Can you be more specific about both your definition of "ragged list" and of "intersection"?

Comment: Show some example inputs and expected outputs

Comment: yes basically a list in list . lst= [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,9,8,7,5],[4,1]], I want to find the intersection but I want a function that takes the list from the user. This is the exact question: Prompt the user to enter a ragged/jagged list containing two items (lists with unique values). Create a function, intersect(), in your program. Pass the ragged list to the function. The function should returns a list containing values that are present in the two sub lists

Comment: enter list:[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,9,8,7,5]]   output = [2,3]

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be written to handle an arbitrary number of sublists by using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

def intersection(ragged_list):
    return [p[0] for p in product(*ragged_list) if len(set(p)) == 1]

print(intersection([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,9,8,7,5]]))
# [2, 3]
```

If you want the user to be able to input the list as a standard Python literal, you could use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

print(intersection(literal_eval(input("Enter list: "))))
```

```
Enter list: [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,9,8,7,5]]
[2, 3]
```

If you need a *function* that inputs the list from the user and prints the intersection, just write `def my_awesome_function():` and put the code inside it.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import product

def intersection(ragged_list):
    """Returns a 1D list representing the intersection of a ragged list."""
    return [p[0] for p in product(*ragged_list) if len(set(p)) == 1]

def my_awesome_function():
    """Takes a ragged list from user input and prints the intersection."""
    print(intersection(literal_eval(input("Enter list: "))))

my_awesome_function()
```

Comment: I'm not following your answer

Comment: It produces `[2, 3]` for your sample input -- is that not what you wanted?  Did you try running the code yourself?

Comment: I want the user to pass the list to the function and then find the intersection

Comment: Did you read the second part of my answer that shows how to use `ast.literal_eval` to do that?

Comment: yes. I am getting closer to what I want. def intersect(a, b):
        a_set = set(a)
        b_set = set(b)
        lst = []

        if (a_set & b_set):
                lst.append(a_set & b_set)
        else:
                print("No common elements")
        return lst
                

a = input("enter list:")
b = input("enter list:")
lst = intersect(a,b)
print(*lst)

Comment: Why don't you just use the code that I posted that does exactly what you want?

Comment: yes I did see the second part of your response but I need it be a function and i do not really understand the second part

Comment: because I need a function. Im getting closer. here is what I have now : def intersect(List):
        intersect_list = []
        for i in List[0]:
                for j in List[1]:
                        if i==j:
                                intersect_list.append(i)
        return intersect_list

#testing the intersect function and its return value
List = input("enter list:")
print(intersect(List))
intersect(List)

Comment: I gave you a function.  Are you saying that you need a function that does both things?

Comment: Added more to my answer.  You can put *any code you want* into a function just by putting it under a `def` statement.  You don't need to rewrite the code from scratch to make it "be a function".

Comment: yes this is what I was trying to do